# Umbraco - Cannot make member programmatically

Tags: umbraco

I want to make registration form in C# on my site using Umbraco 7. I made a form and wrote code:

```
IMember _newMember = ApplicationContext.Current.Services.MemberService.CreateMember("username", "user@email.com", "Full Name", "Member");
ApplicationContext.Current.Services.MemberService.Save(_newMember);
ApplicationContext.Current.Services.MemberService.SavePassword(_newMember, "pass");
```

The form is send correctly, but member still doesn't exist in members list.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Try this (I use `7.1.6` version of Umbraco):

```
        var memSer = Services.MemberService;
        IMember mem = memSer.CreateMember(newUser.UserName, newUser.Email == null ? "mail@mail.com" : newUser.Email, newUser.UserName, "SigneageSystemMember");

        memSer.Save(mem);
        memSer.SavePassword(mem, newUser.Password);
```